# Check extension with RegEx

Tags: regex, apache-flex, actionscript-3

For example I've got string `/wiki/File:test.JPG` I should check if it has one of extention `"jpeg","jpg","png","gif"`

Currently I've written that `link.search(/.[j,p,g][p,i,n][e,g,f][g]?/gi)` and it is works,  but I'd like better regular expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just write the regex as a list:

`/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/gi`

(note the escaped dot (`.`))

EDIT: Added a `$`.

Comment: This also matches `/wiki/File:test.JPGXXX`.

Answer (score 4):

Just for future reference this tool is invaluable when dealing with regex in flash:

Web Version:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Desktop Version:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/desktop/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
/\.(jpe?g|jpg|png|gif)$/gi
```

The dot must be escaped (with a slash) and I wrote $ to point to the fact it needs to be the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var pattern: RegExp = /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/gim
```

Answer (score 1):

If you also want case-insensitive matching try this:

```
 \.(?i)(jpe?g|png|gif)$
```

The dot must be escaped, else it'd match any character :)